# Type "Patient" has no subscript member

Tags: ios, swift, generics, swift2

I have a global class named 'Patient' and a global variable of type 'Patient'

```
class Patient{
var id: Int
var name: String
var mileage: Double

init(id:Int, name:String, mileage:Double){
    self.id = id
    self.name = name
    self.mileage = mileage
}
```

}

```
var pSample: Patient?
```

This is how I assign pSample to the class

```
for var i=0; i<nou; ++i{                   
                pSample = Patient(id: json[0][i]["ID"].intValue, name: json[0][i]["Name"].stringValue, mileage: json[0][i]["Mileage"].doubleValue)   
            }
```

and I plan to use it in the table cell

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("tableCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

    //everything refers to this
    if pSample != nil {
        let patient = pSample![indexPath.row] //error1
        if let nameLabel = cell.viewWithTag(102) as? UILabel{
            nameLabel.text = patient.name
        }

        if let scoreLabel = cell.viewWithTag(103) as? UILabel{
            scoreLabel.text = String(patient.mileage)
        }
    }else{
        let patient = patientSample[indexPath.row] as Patient
        if let nameLabel = cell.viewWithTag(102) as? UILabel{
            nameLabel.text = patient.name
        }

        if let scoreLabel = cell.viewWithTag(103) as? UILabel{
            scoreLabel.text = String(patient.mileage)
        }
    }
```

Why am I getting this error?

Error1: Type Patient has no subscript members

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you getting confused with `[pSample]` and `pSample`? What you did in the for-loop is just updating the one instance you have of Patient.

```
var pSample: [Patient] = []

for var i=0; i<nou; ++i{                   
    pSample += [Patient(id: json[0][i]["ID"].intValue, name: json[0][i]["Name"].stringValue, mileage: json[0][i]["Mileage"].doubleValue)]   
}
```

Comment: after applying your code I'm getting another error -  Type "Element" (aka '(String, JSON)') has no subscript members

Comment: Well, I just used `.forEach`. Actually I've never used json. I'll reedit and use your for loop instead